# Fat Models Skinny Controller in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

i have few controllers within my application which uses too much of business logic in the controllers. for example have a look at this action method

```
public function publishedAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $dataTable = new Model_DataTables('item i', array('i.id', 'i.title', 'i.from_age', 'i.to_age', 'i.gender', 'i.created_at', 'i.ispublished'));
        $item = new Model_Item();
        $output = $dataTable->aaData();
        $iResult = $dataTable->iResult();
        foreach($iResult as $k => $v) {
            $id = $iResult[$k][0];
            $iResult[$k][0] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($iResult[$k][5]));
            $iResult[$k][2] = $item->formatAge($iResult[$k][2], $iResult[$k][3]);
            $iResult[$k][3] = ($iResult[$k][4] == 1) ? 'Male' : 'Female';
            $iResult[$k][4] = "<a href=/admin/item/view/".$id.">View</a>";
            $iResult[$k]['DT_RowId'] = "$id";
        }
        $output['aaData'] = $iResult;
        $this->_helper->json($output);
    }
}
```

with reference to above action method, logic for formatting data is handled in the controller itself. i have several of this methods in the same controller resulting in my controllers becoming fat. while many experienced souls  agree on keeping the controller as skinny as possible. i would like to ask should i move all the business logic for my above method in the corresponding model or it is okay to go with the current flow?

**Update:**

with reference to above code i placed all the business logic in my model

```
public function getPublishedItem()
{
    $dataTable = new Model_DataTables('item i', array('i.id', 'i.title', 'i.from_age', 'i.to_age', 'i.gender', 'i.created_at', 'i.ispublished'));
    $output = $dataTable->aaData();
    $iResult = $dataTable->iResult();
    foreach($iResult as $k => $v) {
        $id = $iResult[$k][0];
        $iResult[$k][0] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($iResult[$k][5]));
        $iResult[$k][2] = $this->formatAge($iResult[$k][2], $iResult[$k][3]);
        $iResult[$k][3] = ($iResult[$k][4] == 1) ? 'Male' : 'Female';
        $iResult[$k][4] = "<a href=/admin/item/view/".$id.">View</a>";
        $iResult[$k]['DT_RowId'] = $id;
    }
    $output['aaData'] = $iResult;
    return $output;
}
```

and in the controller

```
public function publishedAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $item = new Model_Item();
        $this->_helper->json($item->getPublishedItem());
    }
}
```

is it the right approach. or am i doing the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you retrieved `$iResult` from your model (Model_DataTables), wouldn't it be nicer to simply do:

```
public function publishedAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $dataTable = new Model_DataTables('item i', array('i.id', 'i.title', 'i.from_age', 'i.to_age', 'i.gender', 'i.created_at', 'i.ispublished'));
        $output['aaData'] = $dataTable->getIResult();
        $this->_helper->json($output);
    }
}
```

where `getIResult()` contains your foreach.

Another solution would be to use a view helper, since it seems that you are formatting html content. Your action would then be like this:

```
public function publishedAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $dataTable = new Model_DataTables('item i', array('i.id', 'i.title', 'i.from_age', 'i.to_age', 'i.gender', 'i.created_at', 'i.ispublished'));
        $output['aaData'] = $this->view->formatIResult($dataTable->getIResult());
        $this->_helper->json($output);
    }
}
```

where `formatIResult()` is the name of your view helper.

Comment: thank you for dropping in :), if i go your way it will result into multiple view helpers being created since i have many similar action methods which needs data manipulation for iResult. and every iResult variable differs in content and size. isn't it be much nice if i do it directly in the model?

Comment: i am updating the example for how i placed the code in the model and called one line of code in the controller. so now my business logic sits in model and not controller. let me know if i am doing it wrong or it can be improved.

Comment: Multiple view helpers in definitely a bad idea, the option is to take into consideration only if the code can be duplicate. Your new action controller sounds good! And it makes more sense to move everything to the model. Good job. Last thing, consider using AjaxContext with json ;) that would make your action even skinner.

Comment: thank you @Liyali . i am a starter for zend framework and as of for now i haven't used AjaxContent to be frank i am hearing it for the first time from you about it. i will really appreciate if you could fire up some quick example that i could be using with reference to my code. :)

Comment: Sure, I've written [an answer here about AjaxContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833555/json-object-parsing-error-using-jquery-form-plugin/9834576#9834576), take a look at it. You can also find more information about it [in the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext). In your case, your action will only contain : `$item = new Model_Item();` and  `$this->view->aaData = $item->getPublishedItem()` with this technique.